# ASP.NET MVC 4 - return to home controller view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 and I have the home controller with a view and I created an API Controller, what I am trying to do is at the end of my method in my API Controller, to return the user to home controller view. How would I do this?

HomeController

```
namespace ASPNETMVC4_Tutorial.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

My Api Controller

```
namespace ASPNETMVC4_Tutorial.Controllers
{
    public class PersonController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public dynamic Post([FromBody]PersonsClass person)
        {
            person.insertPerson(person);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The api controller is not on charge of handling navigation, it should be client technology agnostic. This means, if the api is well designed and implemented, that you could use it on a mobile application, a web application or any other application type that can use the http protocol.

Url navigation is web specific and that's why can't be there. The correct place to do it on your case would be on `succeed` handler on javascript side.

Comment: I'd also mention that if you need more view logic that MVC can act as a proxy for requests to the API and wrap the results with additional view logic.